# Golangでパッケージからmainパッケージの関数を呼ぶ

Tags: go

例えば下記のようなディレクトリ構成の場合

```
├── controllers
│   ├── controller.go
├── main.go
```

`controllers`パッケージ(`controller.go`)から、`main`パッケージ、すなわち、`main.go`の関数を呼ぶにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

`github.com/<user-name>/<project-name>`をインポートすると、`golint`のエラーは消えましたが、実行すると循環参照はできないとのエラーがでました。

`github.com/<user-name>/<project-name>/main`ではパッケージが見つからないというエラーが出ました。
ご教授ねがえますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controllers` パッケージの関数を呼び出す際に、引数で `main` パッケージの関数を渡します。フックやコールバックを予め登録するという考え方です。

関数の代わりに `interface` を使うという手もあります。`controller` 側で定義された `interface` を満たすように `main` 側に実装し、`controller` を呼び出す前にその実装を渡すイメージです。C言語やJavaとは異なり、golangでは `interface` の実装する際は定義を直接参照する必要がない、充足してさえいれば良いことを利用します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。もし、パッケージがテスト用のパッケージ(`test`パッケージ)であった場合、すなわち`main`パッケージの関数を呼び出す関数が`func Test_Hoge(t *testing.T)`ではどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: golang では、あるパッケージ `A` (`main`に限らない)のテストはそのパッケージ自身に書くべきなので、テストパッケージ `test` を導入するという考え方自体が誤りです。

Comment: わかりました。詳しく教えて頂きありがとうございます。